# How to create post-up and pre-down routes in interfaces file?

Tags: networking, server, routing

I recently installed a new VM using Ubuntu 16.04, but I am unable to copy the `post-up` and `pre-down` rules that I use in my 14.04 install.

Can you please advise what to use? I've added a few notes to indicate what each of my edited out ips are

Example of the 14.04 config:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address x.x.x.109 #vm ip
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        broadcast x.x.x.109 #vm ip
        post-up route add x.x.x.254 dev eth0 #root machine gateway
        post-up route add default gw x.x.x.254 #root machine gateway
        pre-down route del x.x.x.254 dev eth0 #root machine gateway
        pre-down route del default gw x.x.x.254 #root machine gateway
        dns-nameservers 213.186.33.99 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Sorry, but can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Try with `up` and `down` instead of `post-up` and `pre-down`.

Example :

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        up route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1
```

Or, but I didn't test it, you can write a bash script and put it in the folder `/etc/network/if-up.d/` and `/etc/network/if-down.d/` (you can use the variable $IFACE to know which interface is getting a connection).

In `/etc/network/if-up.d/some-script`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $IFACE == "eth0" ]]; then
  ip route add x.x.x.0/24 via x.x.x.254 dev $IFACE
fi
```

Hope this help.