# Route is not deleted

Tags: networking, server, 18.04

I have a machine with Ubuntu 18.04.

with the following /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto ens160
iface ens160 inet static
  address 10.16.21.80
  gateway 10.16.21.254
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  dns-nameservers 10.16.15.1 10.16.15.2 127.0.0.53
  dns-search eqx.solaredge.com



auto ens160:235
iface ens160:235 inet static
address 10.16.15.235
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Each time when I  restart the  machine the routing  of `10.16.15.0` is back to the routing table and I have to delete it manually. Is there another way to disable this route permanently?

I'm running the following command each time:

```
route del -net 10.16.15.0  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I use `/etc/rc.local` for one machine to run this command for each startup but I wonder if there is some other way.

Answer (score 0):

You have a interface in the 10.16.15.0/24 net.

By default Linux will add a route to any local interfaces. How do you expect to contact devices on your 10.16.15.0/24 segment if you do not have a route for it? Do you want traffic to 10.16.15.0/24 to go via 10.16.21.254?

If so, simply remove the interface description for `auto ens160:235`.

The section to remove would be

```
auto ens160:235
iface ens160:235 inet static
address 10.16.15.235
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

To expand the answer a bit.

When you want to send a packet to an address, your OS looks in its routing table. Commonly, the routing table consists of two entries: your local subnet, that's reachable directly, and a default gateway. It may contain any number of routes however.

Routes carry a weight, commonly known as metric. This can be seen in sample output below:

```
default via 10.0.3.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.0.3.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.48 metric 600
```

Routes are selected on basis most specific route, and if two equal routes exists, the lowest metric is preferred. The default route is really 0.0.0.0/0, so it is as unspecific as you get with IPv4. This means that this is a route of last resort, if no other routes match!

You have a directly connected interface, with a netmask of /24, or 255.255.255.0. This is **way** more specific than a netmask of /0, so regardless of weight, it will win. Traffic destined for 10.16.15.0/24 will be sent directly on the `ens160:235` interface, without any routing.

This is probably the behavior you want. If you attach a host to a L2 network segment, it's because you want that host to communicate with other hosts on the same segment, without the overhead of routing.

If you do not want this behavior, I suggest that you explain why you do not want it. It is a non-standard solution, so it may require scripting. The proper way to do that is to [call the script or command when the interface is up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030048/how-to-create-post-up-and-pre-down-routes-in-interfaces-file).

But again, that is probably not what you want.

Comment: Yes, i except the traffic go via 10.16.21.254 , i create the change by network layer, you think just i have to delete the description line and it will be fixes?

Comment: @GidiKalef Updated my answer with what to remove. By default the most specific route wins, and a directly connected subnet is more specific than a default route. It thus has a lower cost and will be preferred.

Comment: but i still need to use this interface if i will remove it , it will be missing and i need to assign a interface in this network

Comment: Why do you need to use this interface, if you will reach this subnet via a router? Your comments are self-contradictory, and either there's something you're not telling us, or there's something you're not understanding.

Comment: This vip used for docker, on the same machine but the docker using a different network

Comment: Then explain your setup in some more detail, including how the docker images are configured.

Comment: we found there was as problem in network infrastructure we had to extend the vlan for more ips,

Comment: @GidiKalef That literally makes no sense. VLANs doesn't care about IP. VLAN is a L2 concept.